# Show that : $\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} I_{A_{i}}\right) \leq c \sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left(A_{i}\right) $

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be a sequence of pairwise independent probability events, show that there exists $c$ such that :

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} I_{A_{i}}\right) \leq c \sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left(A_{i}\right) $$

computing the LHS, we get :

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} I_{A_{i}}\right)  =\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i)+2\left(\sum_{i\neq j}^{1\dots n} P(A_i)P(A_j)\right) - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i)\right)^2 $$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} P^2(A_i) =\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i)(1-P(A_i)) $$

My question is : can $c$ be $\max_{i} (1-P(A_i))$ ?

Comment: Is $I_A$ the indicator function?

Comment: Yes, it can be. Or just $c=1$, since as you showed $Var(\sum_{i=1}^n I_{A_i}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P^2(A_i) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(A_i)$

Comment: @JohnWhite Yes.

Comment: @DominikKutek oh that's smart, indeed $c =1$ is better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your assumptions on $\{A_j:1\leq j\leq n\}$ you have that functions $X_n=\mathbb{1}_{A_n}-\mathbb{P}(A_n)$ are pairwise independent. The variance of the sum of square integrable independent random variables is the sum of the variances; thus

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}\Big(\sum^n_{j=1}\mathbb{1}_{A_n}\Big)&=\mathbb{E}\left(\Big(\sum^n_{j=1}\mathbb{1}_{A_j}-\sum^n_{j=1}\mathbb{P}(A_j)\Big)^2\right)=\operatorname{var}\Big(\sum^n_{j=1}X_j\Big)\\
&=\sum^n_{j=1}\operatorname{var}(X_j)=\sum^n_{j=1}\mathbb{P}(A_j)-\mathbb{P}^2(A_j)\leq \sum^n_{j=1}\mathbb{P}(A_j)
\end{align}$$
since $\mathbb{P}(A)\leq 1$ for all measurable $A$.